# Combine to lists of same type but less fields in each

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to cobine three lists that will always return certain properties out of a list of assets i need to combine these three lists into one list. But not all fields of the master list is filled in

```
           List<Asset> allAssets = new List<Asset>();

            List<Asset> _vheiclesList = new List<Asset>();

            _vheiclesList = getallVechiclesForSlate();

            List<Asset> _propertyList = new List<Asset>();

            _vheiclesList = getAllPropertyForSlate();



            var AllAssets = allAssets.Concat(_vheiclesList)
                                .Concat(_propertyList)
                                .ToList();

            _createCase.Assets = AllAssets;
```

But i am getting a nullable object must have a value and I dont no why.

```
public List<Asset> getAllPropertyForSlate()
    {

        try
        {


        List<tbl_Property> _property = new List<tbl_Property>();
        Asset _asset = new Asset();

        _property = dal.GetPropertiesById(caseid);
        foreach (var property in _property)
        {

            _asset.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            _asset.AssetType =(int) slateExportsConstants.AsssetTypes.Property;

            _asset.Description = property.addressLine1 + " " + property.addressLine2 + property.county + " " + property.country + " " + property.postCode;
            _asset.CurrentValue =(int) Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(property.valueOfProperty.Value));

            string valuationDateIso = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(property.dateofValuation.Value);
            _asset.ValuationDate = valuationDateIso;
            if (property.thirdPartyOwner == new Guid(fhsConstants.fhsPartner))
            {
                _asset.Owner = (int)slateExportsConstants.Applicant.Applicant2;
            }
            else if (property.thirdPartyOwner == new Guid(fhsConstants.fhsExPartner))
            {
                _asset.Owner = (int)slateExportsConstants.Applicant.Joint;              }

            if(property.isHomeAddress==true)
            {
                _asset.Home =(bool) property.isHomeAddress;

            }


                if (property.housingAssoication == true)
            {
                _asset.HousingAssociation = property.housingAssoicationShare.ToString();

            }

            if (property.isHomeAddress == true)
            {
                _asset.Home = true;
            }


            _asset.Equity = Convert.ToInt32(property.valueOfEquity);

            _asset.IsSharedOwnership = property.coOwnerdByAnyOtherParty;

            _assets.Add(_asset);
        }
        return _assets;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }



 public class Asset 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int CurrentValue { get; set; }
        public string ValuationDate { get; set; }
        public int Owner { get; set; }
        public int OutstandingFinance { get; set; }
        public int FinanceAccountHolder { get; set; }
        public int FinanceMonthlyPayment { get; set; }
        public DateTime FinanceEndDate { get; set; }
        public bool Home { get; set; }
        public int AssetType { get; set; }
        public DateTime FixedPeriodEndDate { get; set; }
        public int ValuationSource { get; set; }
        public int Equity { get; set; }
        public bool IsSharedOwnership { get; set; }
        public string HousingAssociation { get; set; }
        public int HousingAssociationShareOfPropertyPercent { get; set; }
        public bool BeneficialInterest { get; set; }
        public int JointOwner1 { get; set; }
        public int JointOwner2 { get; set; }
        public string JointOwner3 { get; set; }
        public int RentalIncome { get; set; }
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string PropertySecuredAgainstId { get; set; }
        public string FinanceCompany { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: @gypsyCoder it was indead the answer supplied by Gary below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it because of the line:

```
_vheiclesList = getAllPropertyForSlate();
```

Should it read:

```
_propertyList = getAllPropertyForSlate();
```

Comment: eyes at the end of the week mate thanks for the help